# Programme a Toggle button to Set Widget update time

Tags: java, android, widget, android-appwidget, togglebutton

```
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(Tb.isChecked()){
        android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE.equals("120000");
    }else{
        android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE.equals("300000");
    }
}
```

I'm developing a widget which has the option for getting updates every 2 min and 30 min. so I made a toggle button to switch between time. The above block of code I'm using to enable the Toggle button known as Tb. The app is not showing errors, but it doesn't seem to be working. Can somebody check my code for errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is not setting anything.

You are testing `ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE` to see if it is equal to "120000" or "300000". `ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE` is a String constant that is always equal to ["android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager.html#ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE).

Therefore, each of those lines do nothing and the `equals()` test which is not evaluated always returns `false`.

Good news is that the following lines of code are probably getting correctly triggered, they just are not the correct way to set interval values:

```
android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE.equals("120000");
android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE.equals("300000");
```

To fix this problem, find another way to set your 2 minute and 30 minute interval values.

Comment: As in the question i do not save it. just code it into a toggle button, so i can name the toggle button as express updates or something in the UI so user can turn it on to get updates quickly. that's all.

Comment: Where to save the update interval in the new widget with a CheckBox that you are developing? Is your widget a class that is extending CheckBox? If so, then we can add the interval as a class variable. Otherwise, please share more about how the interval is accessed and used so we can decide how to change its setting.